# unmet dependencies issues while installing python 3.4 in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, dependencies, python3

I have just upgraded my laptop(its been a week since i have bought it and not used much), while installing python 3.4. I was having some unmet dependencies issues which were as follows:

[This is the image of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEpn1.png)

While i used the code:

```
sudo apt-get install python 3.4

sparsh@sparsh-Inspiron-3558:~$ sudo apt-get install python 3.4
[sudo] password for sparsh: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for sparsh: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for sparsh: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python3.4-dbg:any' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-crypto' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-http-types-dev-0.8.3-4e8ed' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python-lldb-3.4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libdc1394-22' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libllvm-3.4-ocaml-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'clang-3.4-examples' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libassa3.4-0-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libraw1394-11-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-deltarpm' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-icd-304-updates' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libm4rie-0.0.20130416-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.4-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-postgresql-simple-dev-0.3.4.0-e9568' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-postgresql-simple-prof-0.3.4.0-e9568' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-minimal:any' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-cracklib' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libllvm-ocaml-3.4-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-prof-1.0.13-42da6' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-zeroc-ice' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-venv' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-apt' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-304-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libdc1394-22-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libslepc3.4.2' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-opengl-dev-2.8.0.0-344e8' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-zip-archive-prof-0.1.3.4-0faa0' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libclang1-3.4-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libcuda1-304' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.4-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libclang1-3.4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-pylibacl' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'llvm-3.4-examples' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1-304-updates' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-snap-server-dev-0.9.3.4-de7f4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-hastache-prof-0.3.3-4b5e3' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libpetsc3.4.2-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libdc1394-22-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-304-updates-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-basic-prelude-dev-0.3.4.0-8c4a7' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libdc1394-examples' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-reportlab-accel' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-tk' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libzeroc-ice3.4-java' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libslepc3.4.2-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-dev:any' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libavc1394-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libllvm3.4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-newt' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libraw1394-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-sfml' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libpetsc3.4.2-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libdc1394-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-sane' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-esqueleto-dev-1.3.4.2-9652f' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libgnome-desktop-3-4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-gpgme-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-pycangjie' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-icu' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libslepc3.4.2-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-minimal' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-bmp-prof-1.2.3.4-dce3a' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-dev-1.0.13-42da6' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-binary-shared-dev-0.8.2-983a4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-renderpm' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-types-dev-0.3.4-b39fd' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-quickcheck-instances-dev-0.3.4-4dad9' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-epr-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-hastache-dev-0.3.3-4b5e3' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-basic-prelude-prof-0.3.4.0-8c4a7' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-epr' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.4-stdlib' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-kdtree-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-304' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-venv:any' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-opengl-prof-2.8.0.0-344e8' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cipher-blowfish-dev-0.0.3-4855d' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-llfuse' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libcuda1-304-updates' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-snap-server-prof-0.9.3.4-de7f4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-zope.interface' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1-304' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-kyotocabinet' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libdc1394-22-doc' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-ghc-dev-7.6.3-494fa' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libdc1394-utils' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libclang-common-3.4-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libavc1394-tools' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-numpy' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libdbusmenu-gtk3-4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-pyaudio' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'lldb-3.4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libraw1394-doc' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libraw1394-11' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libknewstuff3-4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.4-minimal' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-scrobble-dev-0.2.1.0-79324' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-lxml-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-icu-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-pyxattr-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-doc' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'cupswrappermfc3240c' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-pycurl' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libswt-gtk-3.4-java' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-lxml' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'llvm-3.4-runtime' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-settings-experimental-304' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libswt-gtk-3.4-jni' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-icd-304' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-entropy-dev-0.2.1-37409' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-gearman.libgearman' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'clang-modernize-3.4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4:any' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-ghc-prof-7.6.3-494fa' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libm4rie-0.0.20130416' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-examples' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-pyfits' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'llvm-3.4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'coq-8.4pl3+4.01.0' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'llvm-3.4-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-esqueleto-prof-1.3.4.2-9652f' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libm4ri-0.0.20130416' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-binary-shared-prof-0.8.2-983a4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'cupswrappermfc3340cn' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-http-types-prof-0.8.3-4e8ed' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-settings-304' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libgeos-3.4.2' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libraw1394-tools' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-types-prof-0.3.4-b39fd' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xss-sanitize-prof-0.3.4-f7540' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-quickcheck-instances-prof-0.3.4-4dad9' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-leveldb' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libzeroc-ice-3.4-cil' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-settings-304-updates' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'petsc3.4.2-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-bmp-dev-1.2.3.4-dce3a' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.4-testsuite' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-bsddb3-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-pycurl-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'mfc3240clpr' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'mfc3340cnlpr' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-pyxattr' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-setuptools' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'petsc3.4.2-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-gmpy2' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-bsddb3' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-hunspell' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libavc1394-0' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-304' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'ubuntu-html5-platform-3.4-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python-clang-3.4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-304-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-kdtree' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-scrobble-prof-0.2.1.0-79324' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'llvm-3.4-doc' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-web-routes-happstack-prof-0.23.4-dc5fe' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'clang-3.4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-zip-archive-dev-0.1.3.4-0faa0' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libm4ri-0.0.20130416-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cipher-blowfish-prof-0.0.3-4855d' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-psycopg2' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xss-sanitize-dev-0.3.4-f7540' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-crypto-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libllvm-3.4-ocaml-dev-k31e3' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libevdocument3-4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-gdal' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libllvm3.4-dbg' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'cpp11-migrate-3.4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-304-updates' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-gdbm' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libdc1394-20-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libpetsc3.4.2' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-entropy-prof-0.2.1-37409' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-web-routes-happstack-dev-0.23.4-dc5fe' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'gem-plugin-dc1394' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'clang-format-3.4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'idle-python3.4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'lldb-3.4-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'petsc3.4.2-doc' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-semigroups-prof-0.9-73a41' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libclang-3.4-dev' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-gpgme' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'slepc3.4.2-doc' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'clang-3.4-doc' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'gnat-3.4' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-semigroups-dev-0.9-73a41' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-dbus' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-pytango' for regex '3.4'
Note, selecting 'python3-tk' instead of 'python3.4-tk'
Note, selecting 'python3-apt' instead of 'python3.4-apt'
Note, selecting 'python3-bsddb3' instead of 'python3.4-bsddb3'
Note, selecting 'python3-bsddb3-dbg' instead of 'python3.4-bsddb3-dbg'
Note, selecting 'python3-crypto' instead of 'python3.4-crypto'
Note, selecting 'python3-crypto-dbg' instead of 'python3.4-crypto-dbg'
Note, selecting 'python3-dbus' instead of 'python3.4-dbus'
Note, selecting 'python3-gdbm' instead of 'python3.4-gdbm'
Note, selecting 'python3-gpgme' instead of 'python3.4-gpgme'
Note, selecting 'python3-gpgme-dbg' instead of 'python3.4-gpgme-dbg'
Note, selecting 'python3-icu' instead of 'python3.4-icu'
Note, selecting 'python3-icu-dbg' instead of 'python3.4-icu-dbg'
Note, selecting 'python3-lxml' instead of 'python3.4-lxml'
Note, selecting 'python3-lxml-dbg' instead of 'python3.4-lxml-dbg'
Note, selecting 'python3-newt' instead of 'python3.4-newt'
Note, selecting 'python3-numpy' instead of 'python3.4-numpy'
Note, selecting 'python3-psycopg2' instead of 'python3.4-psycopg2'
Note, selecting 'python3-pycurl' instead of 'python3.4-pycurl'
Note, selecting 'python3-pycurl-dbg' instead of 'python3.4-pycurl-dbg'
Note, selecting 'python3-pylibacl' instead of 'python3.4-pylibacl'
Note, selecting 'python3-pyxattr' instead of 'python3.4-pyxattr'
Note, selecting 'python3-pyxattr-dbg' instead of 'python3.4-pyxattr-dbg'
Note, selecting 'python3-renderpm' instead of 'python3.4-renderpm'
Note, selecting 'python3-reportlab-accel' instead of 'python3.4-reportlab-accel'
Note, selecting 'python3-sane' instead of 'python3.4-sane'
Note, selecting 'python3-zope.interface' instead of 'python3.4-zope.interface'
Note, selecting 'python3.4' instead of 'python3.4:any'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-dbg' instead of 'python3.4-dbg:any'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-dev' instead of 'python3.4-dev:any'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-minimal' instead of 'python3.4-minimal:any'
Note, selecting 'coq' instead of 'coq-8.4pl3+4.01.0'
Note, selecting 'ghc' instead of 'libghc-ghc-dev-7.6.3-494fa'
Note, selecting 'ghc-prof' instead of 'libghc-ghc-prof-7.6.3-494fa'
Note, selecting 'libghc-semigroups-dev' instead of 'libghc-semigroups-dev-0.9-73a41'
Note, selecting 'libghc-semigroups-prof' instead of 'libghc-semigroups-prof-0.9-73a41'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-dev' instead of 'libghc-conduit-dev-1.0.13-42da6'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-prof' instead of 'libghc-conduit-prof-1.0.13-42da6'
Note, selecting 'libghc-http-types-dev' instead of 'libghc-http-types-dev-0.8.3-4e8ed'
Note, selecting 'libghc-http-types-prof' instead of 'libghc-http-types-prof-0.8.3-4e8ed'
Note, selecting 'libghc-basic-prelude-dev' instead of 'libghc-basic-prelude-dev-0.3.4.0-8c4a7'
Note, selecting 'libghc-basic-prelude-prof' instead of 'libghc-basic-prelude-prof-0.3.4.0-8c4a7'
Note, selecting 'libghc-binary-shared-dev' instead of 'libghc-binary-shared-dev-0.8.2-983a4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-binary-shared-prof' instead of 'libghc-binary-shared-prof-0.8.2-983a4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-bmp-dev' instead of 'libghc-bmp-dev-1.2.3.4-dce3a'
Note, selecting 'libghc-bmp-prof' instead of 'libghc-bmp-prof-1.2.3.4-dce3a'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cipher-blowfish-dev' instead of 'libghc-cipher-blowfish-dev-0.0.3-4855d'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cipher-blowfish-prof' instead of 'libghc-cipher-blowfish-prof-0.0.3-4855d'
Note, selecting 'libghc-entropy-dev' instead of 'libghc-entropy-dev-0.2.1-37409'
Note, selecting 'libghc-entropy-prof' instead of 'libghc-entropy-prof-0.2.1-37409'
Note, selecting 'libghc-hastache-dev' instead of 'libghc-hastache-dev-0.3.3-4b5e3'
Note, selecting 'libghc-hastache-prof' instead of 'libghc-hastache-prof-0.3.3-4b5e3'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-types-dev' instead of 'libghc-xml-types-dev-0.3.4-b39fd'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-types-prof' instead of 'libghc-xml-types-prof-0.3.4-b39fd'
Note, selecting 'libghc-snap-server-dev' instead of 'libghc-snap-server-dev-0.9.3.4-de7f4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-snap-server-prof' instead of 'libghc-snap-server-prof-0.9.3.4-de7f4'
Note, selecting 'libghc-esqueleto-dev' instead of 'libghc-esqueleto-dev-1.3.4.2-9652f'
Note, selecting 'libghc-esqueleto-prof' instead of 'libghc-esqueleto-prof-1.3.4.2-9652f'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xss-sanitize-dev' instead of 'libghc-xss-sanitize-dev-0.3.4-f7540'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xss-sanitize-prof' instead of 'libghc-xss-sanitize-prof-0.3.4-f7540'
Note, selecting 'libghc-opengl-dev' instead of 'libghc-opengl-dev-2.8.0.0-344e8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-opengl-prof' instead of 'libghc-opengl-prof-2.8.0.0-344e8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-web-routes-happstack-dev' instead of 'libghc-web-routes-happstack-dev-0.23.4-dc5fe'
Note, selecting 'libghc-web-routes-happstack-prof' instead of 'libghc-web-routes-happstack-prof-0.23.4-dc5fe'
Note, selecting 'libghc-zip-archive-dev' instead of 'libghc-zip-archive-dev-0.1.3.4-0faa0'
Note, selecting 'libghc-zip-archive-prof' instead of 'libghc-zip-archive-prof-0.1.3.4-0faa0'
Note, selecting 'libghc-postgresql-simple-dev' instead of 'libghc-postgresql-simple-dev-0.3.4.0-e9568'
Note, selecting 'libghc-postgresql-simple-prof' instead of 'libghc-postgresql-simple-prof-0.3.4.0-e9568'
Note, selecting 'libghc-quickcheck-instances-dev' instead of 'libghc-quickcheck-instances-dev-0.3.4-4dad9'
Note, selecting 'libghc-quickcheck-instances-prof' instead of 'libghc-quickcheck-instances-prof-0.3.4-4dad9'
Note, selecting 'libghc-scrobble-dev' instead of 'libghc-scrobble-dev-0.2.1.0-79324'
Note, selecting 'libghc-scrobble-prof' instead of 'libghc-scrobble-prof-0.2.1.0-79324'
Note, selecting 'libllvm-3.4-ocaml-dev' instead of 'libllvm-3.4-ocaml-dev-k31e3'
Note, selecting 'libpetsc3.4.2-dbg' instead of 'petsc3.4.2-dbg'
Note, selecting 'libpetsc3.4.2-dev' instead of 'petsc3.4.2-dev'
Note, selecting 'python3-cracklib' instead of 'python3.4-cracklib'
Note, selecting 'python3-deltarpm' instead of 'python3.4-deltarpm'
Note, selecting 'python3-epr' instead of 'python3.4-epr'
Note, selecting 'python3-epr-dbg' instead of 'python3.4-epr-dbg'
Note, selecting 'python3-gdal' instead of 'python3.4-gdal'
Note, selecting 'python3-gearman.libgearman' instead of 'python3.4-gearman.libgearman'
Note, selecting 'python3-gmpy2' instead of 'python3.4-gmpy2'
Note, selecting 'python3-hunspell' instead of 'python3.4-hunspell'
Note, selecting 'python3-kdtree' instead of 'python3.4-kdtree'
Note, selecting 'python3-kdtree-dbg' instead of 'python3.4-kdtree-dbg'
Note, selecting 'python3-kyotocabinet' instead of 'python3.4-kyotocabinet'
Note, selecting 'python3-leveldb' instead of 'python3.4-leveldb'
Note, selecting 'python3-llfuse' instead of 'python3.4-llfuse'
Note, selecting 'python3-pyaudio' instead of 'python3.4-pyaudio'
Note, selecting 'python3-pycangjie' instead of 'python3.4-pycangjie'
Note, selecting 'python3-pyfits' instead of 'python3.4-pyfits'
Note, selecting 'python3-pytango' instead of 'python3.4-pytango'
Note, selecting 'python3-sfml' instead of 'python3.4-sfml'
Note, selecting 'python3-zeroc-ice' instead of 'python3.4-zeroc-ice'
Note, selecting 'python3.4-venv' instead of 'python3.4-venv:any'
libavc1394-0 is already the newest version.
libllvm3.4 is already the newest version.
libraw1394-11 is already the newest version.
python is already the newest version.
python3-crypto is already the newest version.
python3-dbus is already the newest version.
python3-pycurl is already the newest version.
libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 is already the newest version.
libevdocument3-4 is already the newest version.
libknewstuff3-4 is already the newest version.
libknewstuff3-4 set to manually installed.
libpython3.4 is already the newest version.
libpython3.4-minimal is already the newest version.
libpython3.4-stdlib is already the newest version.
python3-apt is already the newest version.
python3-gdbm is already the newest version.
python3-lxml is already the newest version.
python3.4 is already the newest version.
python3.4-minimal is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcuda1-304 : Conflicts: libcuda-5.0-1
 libcuda1-304-updates : Conflicts: libcuda-5.0-1
 nvidia-304 : Conflicts: xorg-driver-binary
 nvidia-304-updates : Conflicts: xorg-driver-binary
 nvidia-libopencl1-304 : Conflicts: libopencl1
 nvidia-libopencl1-304-updates : Conflicts: libopencl1
 nvidia-opencl-icd-304 : Conflicts: nvidia-opencl-icd
 nvidia-opencl-icd-304-updates : Conflicts: nvidia-opencl-icd
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**I DONT KNOW WHY IT IS SHOWING THE NVIDIA ISSUES, I DONT EVEN HAVE NVIDIA GRAPHIC CARD, I HAVE A SIMPLE GRAPHIC CARD.**

I dont know how to solve these unmet dependencies issues, there are several things i want to ask:

1) Since, i bought the laptop just a week ago, while upgrading to 16.04 fron 14.04, i have always got the error of the unmet dependencies. Thus, i am not able to upgrade it. Its been atleast four times that i have changed my laptop settings to factory settings.

2) Due to this my working condition of the laptop has also changed, it has been deteriorated a bit.

3)Please tell me how to solve them using the synaptic package manager or the terminal

4) Did dell gave a bad version of ubuntu 14.04?

Please help, it would be really great

After trying the command ,

```
sparsh@sparsh-Inspiron-3558:~$ sudo apt-get remove libcuda1-304 libcuda1-304-updates nvidia-304 nvidia-304-updates nvidia-libopencl1-304 nvidia-libopencl1-304-updates nvidia-opencl-icd-304 nvidia-opencl-icd-304-updates
```

it showed the follwing output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'libcuda1-304' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libcuda1-304-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-304' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-304-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-304' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-304-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-304' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-304-updates' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Basically i did not have these installed, i dont know why there were unmet dependencies issues with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of fixing it, the hard way and the easy way.

#### The hard way

You didn't type the correct package name for Python Interpreter (v3.4) in your question. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.4
```

In Ubuntu 14.04, this command will install the python3.4 package correctly. Using the Ubuntu Software Center in Ubuntu 14.04 to install software will prevent these types of errors from occurring.

What to do about all the nvidia package dependencies? You don't need the nvidia packages right now, and even if you did need them you could reinstall them later. Meanwhile these conflicting packages are in the way. To remove them all type:

```
sudo apt-get remove ibcuda1-304 libcuda1-304-updates nvidia-304 nvidia-304-updates nvidia-libopencl1-304 nvidia-libopencl1-304-updates nvidia-opencl-icd-304 nvidia-opencl-icd-304-updates
sudo reboot
```

#### The easy way

Ubuntu is not designed to be a cutting edge operating system. It is designed to be an operating system for human beings, in which everything is supposed to work out of the box. Since you just bought the laptop anyway, there is no reason why you shouldn't give up trying to become systems engineer before you've learned how the operating system works, and do a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04.